# Intuitive approach to sequential definition of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

Is there an example which helps to easily understand why, if $f$ is discontinuous, then $f(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n)\ne \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)$?

This is what I've tried: suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ has a jump discontinuity at $a$. Let $x_n := a-a/n$. Then how can we see conceptually (intuitively) that $f(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n)\ne \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)$? What will the value of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)$ be in this case?

Comment: Try a concrete example, like $f(x) = 1$ for $x\ge 0$ and $=0$ otherwise. Now, consider a suitable sequence.

Comment: So the function is discontinuous at 0? $f(-\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}) = f(0) = 1$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(-1/n)=?$. I have no idea.

Comment: yes. What is $f(-1/n)$?

Comment: $0$. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(-1/n)=0$? But this doesn't seem obvious. What if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(-1/n)=1$?

Comment: yes. I don't unterstand your question. Why should the limit of a constantly 0 sequence be $1$?

Comment: Right. I wasn't imagining the concept in a right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a function to be a continuous at a point $x_0$ means that for points $x$ close to $x_0$, $f(x)$ is close to $f(x_0)$. This "closeness" is independent of direction, so for $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, this means it does not matter whether $x$ is a bit less than $x_0$ or a bit more than $x_0$ - as long as they're close, $f(x)$ and $f(x_0)$ will be close.

If a sequence of points $\{x_n\} \to x_0$ and $\{f(x_n)\} \to f(x_0)$, that means that as the $x_n$ get close to $x_0$, the $f(x_n)$ get close to $f(x_0)$. Requiring that this holds true for all sequences tending to $x_0$ captures the "independence of direction" requirement of continuity, hence the equivalence.

For example, if you have a jump discontinuity, i.e. $f(x) = 0$ for $x \leq 0$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $x > 0$, you can pick a sequence of positive numbers converging to $0$ (i.e. $x_n = 1/n$), but $f(x_n) \not\to f(0)$.